# AngularFire How to bind template to a service's Firestore QuerySnapshot

Tags: angular, angularfire

I have  a service containing a function that sets a user's chat name and then gets a query snapshot from my AngularFireStore of all online users like so:

```
setChatName(chatname) {
  this.afs.collection('users').doc(`${this.userDetails}`)
   .set({'chatname': chatname}, {merge: true})
   .then(() => {
     this.userData = this.afs.collection('users').ref.where('online', '==', true)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach(function(documentSnapshot) {
          console.log(documentSnapshot.data()); //outputs correct document snapshot data
          return documentSnapshot.data();
        });
      });
   });
}
```

My problem is in the 5th line where I am attempting assign the documentSnapshot.data() that I can see is correct in my console to the service property, this.userData which is declared as type, DocumentData. Then, I would like to bind to this service property inside my chat component template like so:

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let user of this._authService.userData | async">
    {{user.chatname}}
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

I've tried this several ways.  Results so far come back undefined or it tells me that I can't set a property of undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No need to wait until the promise is complete to set `userData`; you can do it right in init, query in the AngularFire collection function, and use *changes() to get an observable:

```
init(private afs: AngularFireStore) {
  this.userData = this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('online', '==', true)).valueChanges();
  // ... rest of your init
}

setChatName(chatname) {
  this.afs.collection('users').doc(`${this.userDetails}`).set({'chatname': chatname}, {merge: true})
}
```